# how can we control or limit the camera exposure time in ARcore?

Tags: arcore

I am developing an android app that uses ARcore, I would like to limit the exposure time of the camera to no more than 10ms. is it possible in anyway ?

I didn't find any way in the documentations. currently the exposure time varies between 5-20ms automatically, i want to limit it to 10ms or less.